# Someone pressed Shift in The generic off-topic reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, close-reasons, spelling

> [image]
>
> [image]

It's an incredibly minor typo, I know. It's just that it looks weird as heck, and the longer it stays, the more closed questions get stuck with it forever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed. Cue someone posting a "bug" about a different context in which that cap made sense...

Oh - that change applies to all previously-closed questions.

Comment: The casing seems to work fine for every other site on the network... BTW, I'm greatly relieved that this is retroactive.